# How to include React jsx files on the fly instead of all in one go with the react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
// This is straight from the overview.md in the react-router docs
var Router = ReactRouter;
var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
var Link = Router.Link;
var Route = Router.Route;
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
        <div>
            <header>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to="inbox">Inbox</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="calendar">Calendar</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </header>

            {/* this is the important part */}
            <RouteHandler/>
        </div>
        );
    }
});

var Inbox = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                This is the inbox
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Calendar = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                This is the calendar
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var routes = (
    <Route name="app" path="/wish/" handler={App} >
        <Route name="inbox" handler={Inbox}/>
        <Route name="calendar" handler={Calendar}/>
        <DefaultRoute handler={Inbox}/>
    </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function (Handler) {
    React.render(
        <Handler/>,
        document.querySelector('#content')
    );
});
```

The above is a super simple page that shows the inbox component when the user navigates to it and the calender component when navigated to.. however, in reality the pages will likely contain multiple components and lots and lots of jsx code.

What is the best practice to break up all the different components and only download the relavent files when required, ie in the above simple example, only download the code for the inbox when the user requests it (and for the calendar etc? As the JSX files are essentially the views, it seems to go against everything I know to have the user download all the views to only view one.

I had a look around at examples on the net but could only see giant files of 100's of components...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is quite what you are looking for but the best practice is to combine your resources (files) together to eliminate extraneous HTTP requests for lots of small files. There is a balance here (one 5mb js file probably should be broken down into smaller files) and tools like [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/) help manage this for you.

Do you have a specific use case that requires breaking them up?

Comment: Just for ease of working with multiple team members to be honest. I have come from a lamp stack bg where  a project can contain 1000's of files meaning it easier to avoid collisions on files as there is lots of code separation.

Comment: Oh, certainly you can have individual files for each class - but it'd be more difficult to download them only when required (saw that line in your q). They are just JS files, so your HTML page could simply include each file with a <script src="..."/> tag. For totally new projects, you can bootstrap all the things with yeoman: https://github.com/newtriks/generator-react-webpack which will give you a hello-world type app with react, react-router, webpack, testing etc... Thats a great place to start.

Comment: That's awesome! thanks for the tip :D  another module for the heap haha.